# ASN.1 Specification of Size Constraint

Tags: asn.1

In ASN.1, it is valid to write

```
(SIZE(10))
```

Is this equivalent to `(SIZE(10..10))`, `(SIZE(0..10))` or `(SIZE(1..10))`? Or something else? Where is this specified in the standard?

It seems that all parsers interpret it as `(SIZE(10..10))`. However, I was unable to find any specification for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in short: `SIZE(10)` constraints the size of the type to be 10 (and only 10).

---

Detailed explanation with references to the standard:

Size constraint is defined in section 47.5 of X.680

In particular

```
SizeConstraint ::= SIZE Constraint
```

`Constraint` is defined in clause 45.6:

```
Constraint ::= "(" ConstraintSpec ExceptionSpec ")"
ConstraintSpec ::=
    SubtypeConstraint
    | GeneralConstraint
```

GeneralConstraint is defined in X.682 (representing more complex constraints), while SubtypeConstraint is defined in 45.7

```
SubtypeConstraint ::= ElementSetSpecs
```

in 46.1 (here it gets tough... I'll try to expand only the path we need)

```
ElementSetSpecs ::=
      RootElementSetSpec
    | RootElementSetSpec "," "..."
    | RootElementSetSpec "," "..." "," AdditionalElementSetSpec

RootElementSetSpec ::= ElementSetSpec

ElementSetSpec ::= Unions
    | ALL Exclusions

Unions ::= Intersections
    | UElems UnionMark Intersections

Intersections ::= IntersectionElements
    | IElems IntersectionMark IntersectionElements

IntersectionElements ::= Elements | Elems Exclusions
```

in 46.5

```
Elements ::=
    SubtypeElements
  | ObjectSetElements
  | "(" ElementSetSpec ")"
```

in 47.1

```
SubtypeElements ::=
      SingleValue
    | ContainedSubtype
    | ValueRange
    | PermittedAlphabet
    | SizeConstraint
    | TypeConstraint
    | InnerTypeConstraints
    | PatternConstraint
```

Single value is defined in 47.2.1

```
SingleValue ::= Value
```

Value range is defined in the 47.4.1

```
ValueRange ::= LowerEndpoint ".." UpperEndpoint
```

---

So... we're constraining the size of a type (a constraint on type INTEGER), defining a set (`ElementSetSpecs`) of valid values. This set is specified using an expression language that includes optional unions and optional intersections of `Elements`.
`Elements` can be several things (depending on the target type) including either `SingleValue` (indicating a single value) or a `ValueRange` (indicating a close or open range)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the great and detailed answer!